# How to use jars in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, jar

Please tell me if could use jars in iOS development or not ?

I want to use them in my code.

Comment: iOS has frameworks. That's the closest you'll get to Java archives.

Answer (score 2):

Jars are for Java, not Objective-C.  There might be some super-expert way of doing it, but if you have to ask then the answer is effectively no.

You would have better luck using jars in the Android world.

Answer (score 1):

.jar files are effectively ZIP archives with a different extension. And I'm sure you can extract that in your code.
But executing classes from a .jar file won't work since iOS does not come with a JRE.

Answer (score 0):

JAR is a Java Archive.  iOS does not support Java.